# Kali Linux getting stuck on

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kali-linux, kernel, kernel-panic

I've been trying for 2 days now, and Kali keeps giving me this while installing in VirtualBox. I've checked that my virtualisation is turned on and I've tried with 3 different Kali images, 2022.1, 2021 and 2020, but all of them just keep showing this. I tried with the Ova file but that gets stuck at some Soft Lockup. I've been beating my head over this for a long time and it's getting tiring.

I'm on a Windows 11 PC with an Intel Core i7 and an Intel iRIS Xe graphics card. I'm running VirtualBox 6.1. I would go to some other virtualisation software like VMWare, but I want to stick to the course I'm taking because I'm pretty new to this and they've used VirtualBox. Any help would be really appreciated...

[Image of Kali Linux on VirtualBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boPVs.png) (SuperUser won't let me attach images until I'm of higher reputation)

Comment: Make sure your BIOS is set for Hardware Viritualization (VT-d) and make sure you are using the Bare Metal download.  Posted from my Kali 2022.2 machine in VMware on a Windows 11 Pro Host

Comment: @John I've checked with that, it was already enabled for me

Comment: Try making a new Kali machine from the bare metal download to see if that works.

Comment: @John I've tried both bare metal and the ova image. For the bare metal, it gives me the Kernel Panic thing, and for the ova, it gives me a soft lockup

Comment: I think people run Kali on VBOX.   Try reinstalling VBOX.  Try VMware.  I have been running Kali since V2018.